# Contact form only sending certain fields

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a contact form that is only sending certain specific fields and I'm not completely sure why. The Companyname and location is being sent, but the description is not. Here is the script below.

PHP side:

```
$companyname=$_REQUEST['companyname'];
$location=$_REQUEST['location']; 
$description=$_REQUEST['description']; 
if (($companyname=="")||($location=="")||($description=="")) 
    { 
    echo "Company Name, Company Location, and Company Description are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
else{         
    $from="From: <$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="Company Information"; 
    mail("n.dumanov@gmail.com", $subject, $companyname, $location, $description); 

    } 
}
```

HTML form:

```
  <form class="xform" id="admin_form" method="post">
  <label align = "left">Company Name *</label>
  <section class="col col-4">
    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-prepend icon-user"></i> <i class="icon-append icon-asterisk"></i>
      <input type="text" name="companyname" placeholder="Company Name">
    </label>
  </section><br>
       <label align = "left">Company's Province of Operation *</label>
  <section class="col col-4">
    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-prepend icon-user"></i> <i class="icon-append icon-asterisk"></i>
      <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Company's Province of Operation">
    </label>
  </section><br>
       <label align = "left">Company Description *</label>
  <section class="col col-4">
    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-prepend icon-user"></i> <i class="icon-append icon-asterisk"></i>
                <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="Please be as specific as possible. Include information about what kind of work your company does, what sector you operate in, and the type of legal services you will require."></textarea>
    </label>
  </section><br><form>
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: You've got five arguments passed to `mail()`. The [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) says it accepts five arguments. However, check that your five arguments match what the five arguments it's expecting. The last two especially don't appear to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $_POST for getting the form data is the accepted method, but that's not the problem. You have to pass the mail() function one third parameter for the message.

This is how mail() works:

```
bool mail (string $to, string $subject, string $message [,string $additional_headers [,string $additional_parameters ] ] )
```

So, if you want to send the form data as the body of the message, you would have to do something like this:

```
$message = $companyname." ";
$message .= $location. " ";
$message .= $description;
mail("the@mail.com",$subject,$message);
```

Parameters beyond the message are optional and if you set them as you did, you're telling mail() that $location is a string with extra headers and $description other optional parameter.

Read the docs for further information on what headers and extra parameters actually mean:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using $_REQUEST, try using $_POST instead for your PHP on line 1,2 and 3.

Comment: GET? The form clearly says POST. And it's doubtful this will do anything.

Comment: It returns bool(false)

Comment: Try removing the type="text" from the textarea. That shouldn't be necessary for that piece of markup.